# How to add event listeners to jEditable input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, jeditable

How do I add an event listener to a jEditable input?

By default the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key is used to submit, but I need to have other keys as well to submit value?

```
 $('.editable').editable(function(value, settings) { 
     console.log(this);
     console.log(value);
     console.log(settings);
     return(value);
  }, { 
     width: "100%"
     onblur: 'submit'
 });
```

Comment: What other keys do you need to be able to submit?

Comment: # and Space are the ones I need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a `keypress` event listener to the document to listen for those additional keys being pressed.

jEditable adds a `form` with a class of `editable` to the page whenever you start to edit something. Using `.on()` to register the event listener will make sure the handler gets fired even when the `form` block is added to the page dynamically.

**Here's [a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/REbsr/).**

This just shows how you can determine when "space" or "#" are pressed. You'll have to modify the code to work for you.

```
<form class="editable">
  <input type="text" class="editable" />
</form>​

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form.editable').on('keypress', function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 32 || e.keyCode === 35) alert('Time to submit!');
    });
});​
```

Comment: I actually changed jEditable to kisten to the event like it listens the escape key... your solution is cleaner ;)

Answer (score 0):

Jason's solution can't work : jEditable adds form and input on event (click, dbleclick...) so when you executes the function on document ready, they don't exists !

You can modify jEditable adding this code before `input.keydown` :

`input.keyup(function(e){if (e.keyCode === 32 || e.keyCode === 35)     alert('Time to submit!');});`